# Apache mod_rewrite cuting URL

Tags: mod-rewrite

Please help to solve this problem:

http://www.mysite.com/sale/category/subcategory

How I can change it to http://www.mysite.com/subcategory using mod_rewrite

Comment: Welcome to SO! What did you try already?

Comment: Sory didn`t saw your comment. I didn`t try anything yet (I don`t know how to resolve this problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^sale/([A-Za-z0-9_ \-]+)/(.+)$  http://www.mysite.com/$2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thanks it helped, but 'category' is alias and url culd look like

http://www.mysite.com/sale/category1/subcategory2
http://www.mysite.com/sale/category2/subcategory3
http://www.mysite.com/sale/category3/subcategory2